# gst-launch-1.0 no element "hlssink" error

Tags: video-streaming, ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer

I am having trouble creating HLS(HTTP Live Streaming) with gstreamer. I am trying this:

```
gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc is-live=true !  x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5  playlist-root=http://server.com location=/var/www/hlssink playlist-location=/var/www/hlssink
```

and getting the error:

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "hlssink"
```

Can anybody help?
I have tried to install gstreamer-plugins-bad package and gstreamer-libav package. But receiving the same error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For **hlssink** element, there are some dependent packages. So, you have to install them first. Those are

**nettle & libgcrypt**

First You have to install the above packages, and then goto gst-bad-plugins directory, and then

./configure --prefix=< Prefix Path >

make

sudo make install

After configure, it will show the list of plugins which are going to build, In that list if you found hls, Then after make install you will get that element.

Comment: Thanks. I will try.